# Function not returning a recordset

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

**EDIT: 
Answer is at the end of this question, because I couldn't answer the question due to the fact that it was marked as a duplicate.**

I'm new to node and express and am facing a problem while trying to retrieve a recordset from a database.

I have a function in my code that is supposed to get a recordset from a db:

```
// Connection
const db_connection = nconf.get("db");
const connectionPool = new mssql.ConnectionPool(db_connection).connect(err => {
  if (err)
    failureCallback(err);
});

// The function I'm talking about
function getAllUser() {
  connectionPool.query("SELECT * FROM User", (err, result) => {
    if (err)
      failureCallback(err);
    else
      return result.recordset;
  });
}
```

I call this function in my routing at:

```
app.get("/users", (req, res) => {
  res.send(getAllUser());
});
```

The result is... nothing. A blank page - no error.

If I use a function like this:

```
function getAllUser2(callback) {
  connectionPool.connect().then(function () {
    const request = new mssql.Request(connectionPool);
    request.query("SELECT * FROM User").then(function (result) {
      connectionPool.close();
      callback(result.recordset);
    }, failureCallback);
  }, failureCallback);
}
```

And in routing:

```
app.get("/users2", (req, res) => {
  conn.getAllUser(function (err, result) {
    if (err) 
      res.send(err);
    else 
      res.send(result);
  });
});
```

It works. To my understanding, I didn't change much, I just tried to make it more readable/  understandable.

I am grateful for any help and/ or guidance!

***EDIT***:
Although the question got marked as a duplicate and after reading the question/ answer linked to it, I still got the problem and no idea why it's not working. So if anyone can help me I would be really grateful...

With a function like this:

```
test5 = function () {
  return connectionPool.query("SELECT * FROM Objekt", (err, result) => {
    if (err)
      failureCallback(err);
    else {
      console.log("Test 5 success!");
      console.log(result);
      //console.log(recordset);
      console.log(result.recordset);
      //result.recordset;
      result;
    }
  })
};
```

I get this on the page:

```
TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    at JSON.stringify (<anonymous>)
    at stringify (M:\MyFiles\Workspaces\Node_workspace\SPPA\API\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1123:12)
    at ServerResponse.json (M:\MyFiles\Workspaces\Node_workspace\SPPA\API\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:260:14)
    at ServerResponse.send (M:\MyFiles\Workspaces\Node_workspace\SPPA\API\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:158:21)
    at app.get (M:\MyFiles\Workspaces\Node_workspace\SPPA\API\app.js:110:7)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (M:\MyFiles\Workspaces\Node_workspace\SPPA\API\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (M:\MyFiles\Workspaces\Node_workspace\SPPA\API\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (M:\MyFiles\Workspaces\Node_workspace\SPPA\API\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (M:\MyFiles\Workspaces\Node_workspace\SPPA\API\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at M:\MyFiles\Workspaces\Node_workspace\SPPA\API\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
```

But the correct result in console (console.log(result)):

```
{ recordsets: [ [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ] ],
  recordset:
  [ { id: '3FCB9E85-CEB1-41F1-84B4-4A9912345678',
  anmeldename: 'lustig_pe',
  email: 'peter.lustig@company.com',
  istAdmin: false },
{ id: '04B142F1-1A5C-4B97-A173-650C12345678',
  anmeldename: 'durden_ty',
  email: 'tylor.durden@company.com',
  istAdmin: true },
{ id: 'A5019258-2CC7-4794-A924-65F812345678',
  anmeldename: 'sarpei_ha',
  email: 'hans.sarpei@company.com',
  istAdmin: true },
{ id: 'BAFF838E-B606-4DC8-AEF6-DED612345678',
  anmeldename: 'mustermann_ma',
  email: 'max.mustermann@company.com',
  istAdmin: false } ],
  output: {},
  rowsAffected: [ 4 ] }
[ { id: '3FCB9E85-CEB1-41F1-84B4-4A9912345678',
    anmeldename: 'lustig_pe',
    email: 'peter.lustig@company.com',
    istAdmin: false },
  { id: '04B142F1-1A5C-4B97-A173-650C12345678',
    anmeldename: 'durden_ty',
    email: 'tylor.durden@company.com',
    istAdmin: true },
  { id: 'A5019258-2CC7-4794-A924-65F812345678',
    anmeldename: 'sarpei_ha',
    email: 'hans.sarpei@company.com',
    istAdmin: true },
  { id: 'BAFF838E-B606-4DC8-AEF6-DED612345678',
    anmeldename: 'mustermann_ma',
    email: 'max.mustermann@company.com',
    istAdmin: false } ]
}
```

Any ideas?

**EDIT: 
I found a solution but I can't answer my question (I guess because it is marked as a duplicate), so I will show it here in the question:**

```
// This is the function you want to call in the routing:
function getFoo() {
  try {
    return connectionPool.query("SELECT * FROM Foo");
  }
  catch (err) {
    return err.message;
  }
}

// In routing you have to add **async** to the callback function 
// and add **await** next to the function you are calling. 
// This works now!
app.get('/v2/anhang', async (req, res) => {
  res.send(await getFoo());
});
```

I also want to point out that the linked question (with its answers) to this seemingly "duplicate" question did not help me at all. I tried so many things in the function that I was trying to call in the routing, that I forgot about the callback function **in** the routing... So I hope this will help beginners with a similar problem, so that they dont have to read mostly unrelated stuff and waste their time.

Comment: you are not returning anything from the function, neither are you calling callback function in getAllUser().

Comment: @ Abhishek Anand: Thank you. Could you go more into detail please?

Comment: I still got the problem, so if anyone can help me that would be much appreciated!

Comment: can you tell me the result of console.log(Object.keys(result)) and if throws an an error, check if result i an array. I have not used mssql, so idk how the driver handles them;

Comment: @[Abhishek Anand](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8380177/abhishek-anand): Sure. I edited the question to show the console output. Thank you for your effort!

Comment: I got a answer/ solution now but I can't answer my question (I guess because it is marked as a duplicate). 

I will edit the question to show the correct answer/ solution.

Answer (score 1):

you are not returning anything from the function, neither are you calling callback function in getAllUser().

Try this:

```
function getAllUser() {
   return new Promise(resolve=>{
       connectionPool.query("SELECT * FROM User", (err, result) => {
    if (err)
      failureCallback(err);
    else
      resolve(result.recordset)
  });
   })
}
```

Comment: Thank you but it's still not working correctly (page returns { })... No recordset.